# Is it possible to run a python script as an administrator programatically on Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows

I am facing a problem which I cannot seem to solve after trying nearly everything.

I need to have a python script to run with administrator privileges, without the use of cmd and without the script being converted into an executable.
Is there any way to programatically do this? I am using python 3.4.3
Sorry if this sounds like a silly question.
Thanks.

-Charles

Comment: you can using task scheduler and this question should be on SuperUser as that is probably the better match

Comment: You can `ShellExecute` the interpreter with the `"runas"` command to restart the script as an elevated process. But that involves a UAC prompt. The only way to do this silently is with a task or service. You can create and run a task via schtasks.exe, but the script will have to be elevated on the first run in order to create the task.

Comment: For this case, I do not mind if there is a UAC prompt. I assume you mean the pywin32 module for ShellExecute?

Comment: I feel ridiculous right now after spending ages finding the answer for this. I have finally been able to launch a python script with administrator privileges with ShellExecute like eryksun said. Thank you.